# Calculate the minimum and maximum size of a page table

Tags: operating-system, page-tables

Given a logical address space of 32 bits, a memory of 8 MB and and page size of 4 KB, calculate the maximum size of 2 level Hierarchical Paging table. Each entry contains an additional 4 bit control sequence.

I have calculated the number of frames to be 2^11, and therefore each entry in the lowest level must consist of 15 bits(11 to identify frame number and 4 for control). I have rounded it to 16 for and easier calculation.

I have broken down the logical 32 bit address starting from my LSB into 12 bits for physical memory offset, 11 bits for inner page offset(considering each entry a page is 2 bytes) and 9 for outer page.

When only a single process is using the memory I need one page for my outer table and one page for my inner table and therefore need only 8 KB for the table.

However i'm having some trouble with the maximum case. If the entire logical address space is in use how much space does the table take ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets write what we know

```
32 bits logical address space
8 MB RAM
4 KB page size
9 bits for outer page table
11 bits for inner page table
```

If all the logical memory space is mapped: then you have `2^9` entries from level 1 each pointing into a second level page table containing `2^11` entries.

So for second level page tables you have `2^9` of those, each one has `2^11` entries. That is: **(2^9)*(2^11)*2B = 2MB**

So for all the second level page tables you need **2MB**

Now what about the outer page ? 
You have one, which has 2^9 entries, each entry of size 2B.

That is 1KB, but since pages are 4KB of size, it will get a whole page.

So the answer is: 2MB + 4KB, the 4KB is because the OS allocates memory in pages, even though the outer table needs only 1KB.